# Firefox 30 javascript bug in array handling

Tags: javascript, firefox

Can someone explain me this behaviour in firefox?

*Reduced code snippet*

```
function Calc(val,str, cmd,stack)
{
  console.log(str, cmd, stack);

  while(c = cmd.pop())
  {
     if (c=='0') stack.push(val);
  }
  console.log(str,cmd, stack)
}

var k,i,l,s;

k=3;
for (i=1;s=i.toString(6), !s[k]; i++)
{
    l=s.split(0).length;
    if (l+l-1==s.length) 
    {
      Calc(1,s, (s+'00').split(''), [])
    }
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eQKTX/1/

In Firefox 30.0, from a certain point on, the string **split cease to work**.
I tried with split and with spread operator [...] and it's the same.
I think the `cmd.pop` inside the Calc function is the culprit. Pop does change the array, but the function sholud get a brand new array on each call.

It works flawlessy in Chrome and MSIE 10

Comment: What does your code do? What is it supposed to do?

Comment: @amoebe My code as a whole is suppost to do prefix calculations. The code snippet should log to console 55 calls to a function with a parameter array of variabile content. Instead after some calls, the array is empty and stay empty. Look yourself, the demo is 1 click away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the code does,
but I confirmed that logged data is different in Chrome and Firefox.

in Chrome

```
1 ["1", "0", "0"] []
1 [] [1, 1]
...
```

in Firefox

```
"1" Array [  ] Array [ 1, 1 ]
"1" Array [  ] Array [ 1, 1 ]
...
```

I guess the reason is that `console.log` runs asynchronously in Firefox.

This may be related bug:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=754861#c7

When former `console.log` is called, `stack` is empty array,
but `stack` is modified just after the call,
and the modified data is used for logging.

If I add `JSON.stringify` to `console.log`, both Chrome and Firefox outputs same log,
so I guess there is no other different behavior.

```
console.log(JSON.stringify([str, cmd, stack]));
```